# JavaScript - Iterate over dynamically create html

Tags: javascript, loops, constructor, prototype, selector

I am trying to write a constructor function with a method that loops over a number of rows (numerical argument), and for each of the individual rows then loops over a number of dots(numerical argument). In Each of the two loops a portion of html will be rendered. I can get the first portion html to render but when i try to loop over second portion using a selector from the previously rendered html nothing happens. What am i missing ?

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="container">
   <h1 class="heading">Random Colors</h1>
   <div class="row">
       <div id="frame" class="col-xs-12">
           <!-- CONTENT PUSHED BY JAVASCRIPT -->     
       </div>  
   </div><!-- Ends .row -->  
</div><!-- Ends .container -->
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
var ColorDots = function(rows, dots) {
    this.numOfRows = rows;
    this.numOfDots = dots;
    this.renderDots();

};

ColorDots.prototype.renderDots = function() { 

    this.rowTemplate = '<div class="color-dot row"></div>';
    this.iconTemplate = '<i class="fa fa-circle icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>';     

    for ( var r = 0; r < this.numOfRows; r++) {

        document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML += this.rowTemplate;

        for ( var i = 0; i < this.numOfDots; i++) {

            document.getElementsByClassName('color-dot').innerHTML += this.iconTemplate;
        }            
    }    
};
```

**SOLUTION** (javascript only)

```
    var ColorDots = function(rows, dots) {

        // Properties
        this.numOfDots = dots;
        this.numOfRows = rows || 1;
        this.iconHtml = '<i class="fa fa-circle icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>';

        this.renderRows();

    };    

    ColorDots.prototype.renderRows = function() { 

        this.rowHtml = ''; 

        for ( var r = 0; r < this.numOfRows; r++) {

             this.rowHtml += '<div class="color-dot row">';

            for ( var i = 0; i < this.numOfDots; i++) {            
                 this.rowHtml += this.iconHtml;
            }  

            this.rowHtml    += '</div>';
        }

        document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML = this.rowHtml;

};
```

Thank you @rainerh for giving me the answer to my question. How ever after considering what @shilly said in the comment in regards to using `.innerHTML` within for loops i made some changes to my code to reflect his suggestion. Hopefully this will be useful for other trying to do something similar to me.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is returning an array of elements. So `innerHTML` won't work. You have to iterate through the elements you get returned.

Comment: Sidenote: Try to avoid setting innerHTML in a loop. Append all the elements to a string and do one innerHTML once the string is complete. This will drastically increase render time ocne you get to alot of rows.

Comment: @Shilly, thank you for the advise i added a revised code example to the question that reflects your comment and of course it works just fine for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the css class is color-dot and not color-dots as you have it in your selector.

Secondly getElementsByCLassName returns an array. So have to use an index here.

```
ColorDots.prototype.renderDots = function() { 
  this.rowTemplate = '<div class="color-dot row"></div>';
  this.iconTemplate = '<i class="fa fa-circle icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>';     

  for ( var r = 0; r < this.numOfRows; r++) {

    document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML += this.rowTemplate;
    for ( var i = 0; i < this.numOfDots; i++) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('color-dots')[r].innerHTML += this.iconTemplate;
    }            
  }    
};
```

Comment: thanks, i knew i would have to iterate over the collection at some point i was just getting myself confused as to when, where and how. You suggestion was very helpful.